# Fourier Series for $f(x)=x, 0<x<\pi$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

I am trying to find the Fourier series, using integration and known knowledge of the Fourier Series, of:

$$f(x)= x, \quad 0<x<\pi$$

I know the $f(x)= x$ is an odd function and so I believe that $a_n = 0$.

I then worked through to find $b_n$ using:

$$b_n=\displaystyle{\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x) \sin \frac {nx\pi}{L} dx}$$

But when I finally put everything together I didn't end up getting what I wanted. I know that for $0<x<\pi$ that I will end up with a partial sawtooth wave, however, I just can't get it.

Any help would be appreciated. Also sorry for the formatting if it is wrong, I can never seem to get that as well.

Comment: Why don't you derive the coefficients using orthogonality conditions yourself? Or use the fact that your integrand is the product of odd functions and hence _even_, so you can solve it as $$b_{n} = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} x \sin (nx) dx$$

Comment: The extension of $f(x)$ to a $\pi$-periodic function on the whole real line isn't odd, so $a_n \neq 0$.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Fourier/Series/ExFS.html).